# Java Swing - How a JTree and a JLabel can talk each other?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtree

This is my tiny app made by a `JTree` and a `JLabel`.

The **goal** is simple: once I click on a `JTree`node I should see that value inside the `JLabel`.

Here the image to make things clear:
[image: *JTree and JLabel*]

My code is already able to get the node's name once I click on it.

The **problem** is to find a way to make possible the communication between these 2 components, in order to fill the `JLabel`.

```
/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MyJtree() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][grow]", "[grow]"));



    JTree tree = new JTree();
    tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            String str = retrieveNodeName(e, tree);
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(tree, "cell 1 0,grow");

    JLabel lblCurrentnode = new JLabel("CurrentNode");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblCurrentnode, "cell 0 0");
}

//Detect node name
private String retrieveNodeName(MouseEvent me, JTree jtree) {
    TreePath tp = jtree.getPathForLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
    if (tp != null)
    {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: " +tp.getLastPathComponent());
    }
    return tp.getLastPathComponent().toString();

}
```

I found a workaround to solve this, but I'm aware it's not the best solution especially for more components. It consists in putting the JLabel *before*,
in order to access its value inside the mouse listener.

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][grow]", "[grow]"));

    JLabel lblCurrentnode = new JLabel("CurrentNode");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblCurrentnode, "cell 0 0");

    JTree tree = new JTree();
    tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            String str = retrieveNodeName(e, tree);
            lblCurrentnode.setText(str); //cheap solution
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(tree, "cell 1 0,grow");


}
```

Not the best way.

Is there a specific way to approach this kind of problem?

Comment: This is Java at it's most basic as your problem appears to be one of basic variable scope -- make your JLabel a private instance field of the class, not a local variable, so that now it is visible throughout the class -- that's it.

Comment: Same thing for the JTree and its model

Comment: I though that MVC pattern would be a solution, but it seems that this approach is even quicker. Am I right?

Comment: After adding the gui components, just then add the listener. So the order is irrelevant.

Comment: But yes, MVC is good for simplifying complexity (cyclomatic complexity) but would appear to be over-kill in this situation

Comment: Solved! As you suggested, make JTree and JLabel private instance field. Then call the listeners. Many thanks!